# PWA cache.addAll not working within ASP.NET project

Tags: javascript, caching, scope, promise, progressive-web-apps

I am building a Progressive Web App and am currently using a Service Worker to build the app shell with a couple of static image files

With the code below the cache.addAll returns the following error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

```
var appShellCacheName = 'mike-tss-appShell-v1';

var filesToCache = [    
    "/media/1014/newyork.png",
    "/media/1018/london.png",
    "/media/1015/boston.png"
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(appShellCacheName).then(function (cache) {
            console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
            console.log(filesToCache);
            return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
        })
    );
});
```

There is no CORS and the 3 files all exist. I am running this on Chrome version 64

When registering the service worker (which is in a `scripts/` directory), I am giving it scope of the root

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register("./scripts/my.serviceworker.js", { scope: "/" })
```

and also adding

```
<add name="Service-Worker-Allowed" value="/" />
```

to the web.config

It seems the Service Worker just cannot see the assets to cache

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't reference the png files correct.
This worked for me:

```
var filesToCache = [    
    "../media/1014/newyork.png",
    "../media/1018/london.png",
    "../media/1015/boston.png"
];
```